# PLSQL Find Matching Values in Array

Tags: arrays, oracle, collections, plsql, oracle10g

I have an array where I am assigning values to array as

```
TYPE array_p IS ARRAY (10000) OF VARCHAR2 (100);
my_array   array_p := array_p();

loop 
my_array.EXTEND;
my_array (my_array .LAST) :=
           'Product Id - '
        || product_Id
        || ', Product Item - '
        || product_Item
        || ', Amount -'
        || amt;
.....
```

How can I find there are matching `product_Id` and `product_Item` in my_array during iteration?

Comment: Do you need to use an array?  Can you not use a nested table instead?

Comment: You can use nested tables in PL/SQL, like I did.

Comment: I will try this approach. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use MULTISET operators to interrogate nested table collections.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions006.htm#SQLRF52137).

For instance, this sample code employs MEMBER OF to test for the existence of an entry in a nested table, and IS A SET to test for uniqueness.

```
declare
    my_array sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := new sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll();
    str varchar2(4000);
begin
    for product in ( select '1' as id, 'iron' as item from dual union all
                     select '2' as id, 'gold' as item from dual union all
                     select '1' as id, 'iron' as item from dual union all
                     select '3' as id, 'redstone' as item from dual union all
                     select '4' as id, 'diamond' as item from dual 
               )
    loop
        str :=  'Product Id - '
                || product.Id
                || ', Product Item - '
                || product.Item;
        if str not member of my_array
        then
            my_array.extend();
            my_array(my_array.count()) := str;
        end if;
    end loop;    
    dbms_output.put_line('my_array count = '||to_char(my_array.count()));
    if my_array is a set then
        dbms_output.put_line('my_array has only unique entries ');    
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('my_array has duplicated ');  
    end if;
end;
/
```

For the record, the output is ...

```
my_array count = 4
my_array has only unique entries

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

> "I am getting error wrong number of arguments in call to SET."

Now that you have included the definition I realise that you meant 'array' specifically rather then generically.  MULTISET operators work with nested tables but not VARRAY collections.  This is one of many limitations of VARRYAY, and one reason (of several) why developers rarely use VARRAY collections.  In fact, unless there is a cast-iron requirement to preserve the order of insertion there is no real reason to prefer them over nested tables.

Comment: I have tried as 
    `IF my_array  IS A SET THEN
    message('no');
   else
    message('yes');
     END IF;` However I am getting error `wrong number of arguments in call to SET`. My array definition is different from yours though.

Comment: I have included in my question, top two lines are array definition. Thanks

Comment: I have another doubt, how to fetch identical rows from collection?

Comment: That's a separate question.  Be sure to include more detail when you ask it.

Comment: I have created another question to find out duplicates from collection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883211/find-duplicates-in-plsql-collections